# how to find key in json comes after variable key with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

how to find the "display_url" value after finding a certain id { id": 2799869337379524745 }

the main goal is to get only the display_url value after finding this key "id" with this value " 2799869337379524745 "

as you can see in this JSON there are 3 id/display_url keys that are the same but with different values
is there is a way to search for the display_url and get it if the script finds a certain id before it?

```
{
    "status_code": 0,
    "data": {
        "__type": "GraphSidecar",
        "items": [
            {
                "__type": "GraphImage",
                "title": "",
                "id": 2799854276157690472,
                "shortcode": "",
                "display_url": "https://instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/276983984_1278084093013655_9426266357493227_n.jpg?se=7&stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=Agd6tOmDwWIAX9QRl47&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=Mjc5OTg1NDI3NjE1NzY5MDQ3Mg%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT81fTAWNb5z4xRKSvrlzYikB9SFH9fqC_Vz3Q_mpowzeA&oe=623CE3A3&_nc_sid=643ae9",
                "stats": {
                    "view_count": null,
                    "play_count": null,
                    "like_count": null,
                    "comment_count": null
                },
                "items": [
                    {
                        "width": 1284,
                        "height": 2282,
                        "url": "https://instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/276983984_1278084093013655_9426266357493227_n.jpg?se=7&stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=Agd6tOmDwWIAX9QRl47&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=Mjc5OTg1NDI3NjE1NzY5MDQ3Mg%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT81fTAWNb5z4xRKSvrlzYikB9SFH9fqC_Vz3Q_mpowzeA&oe=623CE3A3&_nc_sid=643ae9"
                    },
                    {
                        "width": 412,
                        "height": 732,
                        "url": "https://instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/276983984_1278084093013655_9426266357493227_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_p412x412&_nc_ht=instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=Agd6tOmDwWIAX9QRl47&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=Mjc5OTg1NDI3NjE1NzY5MDQ3Mg%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT-Xh-RhlnxuYDEbpeybauDuzBljduFDo7gv605PN0waBA&oe=623CE3A3&_nc_sid=643ae9"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "__type": "GraphVideo",
                "title": "",
                "id": 2799869337379524745,
                "shortcode": "",
                "display_url": "https://instagram.frao1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/276982171_368041468652651_1129111111982125674_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e15&_nc_ht=instagram.frao1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=111&_nc_ohc=Bn_fivVURfkAX96vioj&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&ig_cache_key=Mjc5OTg2OTMzNzM3OTUyNDc0NQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4&oh=00_AT82hfShwy8jgWnML_r9NwT5XHtz-GPo87AzP4WWLQLtQA&oe=623C67C8&_nc_sid=643ae9",
                "stats": {
                    "view_count": null,
                    "play_count": null,
                    "like_count": null,
                    "comment_count": null
                },
                "video_url": "https://instagram.frao1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/o1/v/t16/f1/m38/8B411302C790D400BFC917327ED000AB_video_dashinit.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjcyMC5zdG9yeS5iYXNlbGluZW9pbCJ9&_nc_ht=instagram.frao1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=109&vs=1016973519224456_2663807264&_nc_vs=HBkcFQIYRGlnX3hwdl9lcGhlbWVyYWwvOEI0MTEzMDJDNzkwRDQwMEJGQzkxNzMyN0VEMDAwQUJfdmlkZW9fZGFzaGluaXQubXA0FQACyAEAKAAYABsBiAd1c2Vfb2lsATEVAAAmpNTf%2FLKO3z8VAigCQzMsF0AUAAAAAAAAGBVkYXNoX2Jhc2VsaW5lb2lsXzJfdjERAHXoBwA%3D&ccb=9-4&oe=623C67A5&oh=00_AT9fX3pzP1tg9MGCgA18lLMSNruXo4AZqemBNVmOFfLhDQ&_nc_sid=643ae9",
                "video_duration": 5
            }
        ],
        "owner": {
            "id": 2964949070,
            "username": "bellapoarch",
            "avatar_url": "https://instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/264213838_416586213515696_109261969756357041_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=instagram.frao1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=bqlIwmkMbyQAX-5SGh_&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9FyyuMiYsJO1E2DckN_m0ow5_KLRDFgr8FXY2US_wT7Q&oe=62413ECB&_nc_sid=643ae9"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take that `items` array (and forget every thing around it), search for an object in it that has the id you want. Take that object, and take its `display_url` property. See link in box at the top.

Comment: Right.  Don't think of "before" and "after" with dictionaries.  They're both just keys in the same dict.  `for i in j["data"]["items"]:` / `if j["id"] == 2799869337379524745:` / `return j['display_url']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for i in data['data']['items']:
    if i['id'] == 2799869337379524745:
        print(i['display_url'])
```

is this what your looking for?